# Cannot install Ubuntu at ext4 partition from FAT32 bootable USB stick

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, usb, fat32

I am trying to install a 14.04.5 64 bits Ubuntu in a machine with several partitions, one of which is already running a 12.04 64 bits Ubuntu, into one that is empty and formatted as ext4. I have created a bootable Ubuntu USB following the instructions of https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#3, but when I try to install I get an error message that says:

No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found!
boot: _

and I do not know how to follow.

I have also tried to use Universal USB installer but the result is that the screen remains blank for eternity just with the prompt, which does not admit any command. I have changed the name of the isolinux files and folder to syslinux, as I have seen in other threads with similar isues, but to no avail.

Rather than because of the tool, I believe this is related to the fact that when I have the USB formatted to have the Ubuntu distribution installed in it, it is done so as FAT32, rather than ext4, so perhaps it is not recognized at all. Is there any way to me to change the format of the USB from FAT32 to ext4, or this is not related at all? I understand (correct me if I am wrong) that FAT32 is an obsolete format and ext4 should be used for Ubuntu instead. I am toatlly open to use an ext4 USB bootable stick, but I do not know any tool that may do the job (rufus 2.15 and universal USB installer 1.9.7.8 do not offer ext4 as an option).

Any help to solve this will be more than welcome.

Comment: Use RaWrite32 to make a bootable USB. [Link](https://www.netbsd.org/~martin/rawrite32/download.html). I use this software all the time.

Comment: Not only it has not worked but also it was unrecognizable by Windows. When formatting, it has dramatically reduced the capacity that can be seen of the USB in Windows after using it, it has created two partitions.

Comment: I just downloaded a fresh ISO from ubuntu and tested it in my windows. The bootable device was build successfully.  Run the application, select the ISO then select the USB from the dropdown menu. And then click Write. There is no reason this shouldn't work. Try downloading the ISO from ubuntu again? Maybe it's corrupted?

Comment: When I launch it in my PC it says that the isolinux.config file is missing after launching the USB generated with the tool you mentioned; I have tried it twice but to no avail. After formatting the USB again and generating the bootable USB with niversal USB Installer I have also tried to boot it without chaning the name of the files (keeping them as isolinux) but it does not work. Sometimes I would get a message saying that the isolinux.bin file was missing or corrupt so I downloaded the same image again. Unfortunately it still says that the isolinux file is missing or corrupt.

Comment: Both Rufus and YUMI use the latest version of Syslinux, it can install the bootloader to NTFS and EXT.

Comment: Syslinux supports ext but Win apps like Rufus and YUMI don't, I think because Windows doesn't, MultiBootUSB for Linux will install to ext4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to solve the issue by just using a different Flash memory. Apaprently, the one that I was using before either was damaged or had other kind of problem. Thanks everyone for their help anyway.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-) Maybe you can use the following link to analyze similar problems in the future (problems with the hardware of a USB flash drive or memory card), https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035